# FluentNHibernate: What is the effect of AsSet()?

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

In Fluent Nhibernate what is the effect of specifying AsSet() on a HasMany or HasManyToMany relationship?

Assuming the type of the mapped property is an Iesi Set, is there any difference between:

```
HasMany(x => x.MySetProperty)
   .AsSet();
```

and

```
HasMany(x => x.MySetProperty);
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assuming your type is an Iesi Set, then there's no difference; the `HasMany` call on it's own is smart enough to figure out that you want a Set. The `AsSet` is a way to explicitly change your HasMany to a Set in situations where FNH might not be able to determine it by type, for example if you're exposing your collection as an `IEnumerable` it would default to a Bag and calling `AsSet` would override that.