# FluentNhibernate Eager loading Many-To-Many child objects

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, many-to-many, eager-loading

I try to query data using **FluentNhibernate** and I get this error: **"Sequence contains more than one matching element"**

Here are my classes and mappings:

```
public class Course
{
    public virtual int Id { get; private set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Instructor> Instructors { get; set; }
}

public class Instructor
{
    public virtual int Id { get; private set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ImageData Portrait { get; set; }
    public virtual ImageData PortraitThumb { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Course> TeachingCourses { get; private set; }
}

public class ImageData : Entity
{
    public virtual int Id { get; private set; }
    public virtual byte[] Data { get; set; }
}

public class CourseMap : ClassMap<Course>
{
    public CourseMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.Name);
        HasManyToMany(x => x.Instructors)
            .Cascade.All()
            .Table("CourseInstructor");
    }
}

public class InstructorMap : ClassMap<Instructor>
{
    public InstructorMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x=> x.Name);
        References(x => x.Portrait)
            .Nullable()
            .Cascade.All();
        References(x => x.PortraitThumb)
            .Nullable()
            .Cascade.All();
        HasManyToMany(x => x.TeachingCourses)
            .Cascade.All()
            .Inverse()
            .Table("CourseInstructor");
    }
}

public class ImageDataMap : ClassMap<ImageData>
{
    public ImageDataMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.Data);
    }
}
```

Then I try to get data using below code:

```
var course = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Course))
               .SetFetchMode("Instructors", FetchMode.Eager)
               .SetFetchMode("Instructors.Portrait", FetchMode.Eager)
               .SetFetchMode("Instructors.PortraitThumb", FetchMode.Eager)
               .List<Course>();
```

But I get the following error: "Sequence contains more than one matching element"
Also, when I try this

```
var course = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Course))
               .SetFetchMode("Instructors", FetchMode.Eager)
               .SetFetchMode("Instructors.Portrait", FetchMode.Eager)
               .SetFetchMode("Instructors.PortraitThumb", FetchMode.Eager)                   
               .SetResultTransformer(new DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer())
               .List<Course>();
```

No error occurs but I get duplicate `Instructor` objects.

I did try below posts and some others as well. But it doesn't help.

- [NHibernate Eager loading multi-level child objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563250/nhibernate-eager-loading-multi-level-child-objects)
- [Eager Loading Using Fluent NHibernate/Nhibernate & Automapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142845/eager-loading-using-fluent-nhibernate-nhibernate-automapping)

Comment: Can you post what you expect to retrieve and what you actually retrieve? I suppose the issue is caused by the usage of `IList` instead of `ISet`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FluentNhibernate uses a `bag`-mapping for many-to-many relations, if the mapped property is of type `IList`.

A `bag` mapping has a few major drawbacks [Performance of Collections / hibernate](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-collections). The one that currently bites you is that NH does not permit duplicate element values and, as they have no index column, no primary key can be defined.

Simply said NH does not know to which `bag` do they belong to when you join them all together.

Instead of a `bag` I would use a indexed variant a `set`, assuming that an `Instructor` does not has the same persistent `Course` assigned twice.

You can fix your query results by amending your domain classes, this tells FluentNhibernate to use a `set` instead of a `bag` by convention:

```
public class Course
{
    public virtual int Id { get; private set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Iesi.Collections.Generic.ISet<Instructor> Instructors { get; set; }
}

public class Instructor
{
    public virtual int Id { get; private set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ImageData Portrait { get; set; }
    public virtual ImageData PortraitThumb { get; set; }
    public virtual Iesi.Collections.Generic.ISet<Course> TeachingCourses { get; private set; }
}
```

In addition you can amend your mapping by using `.AsSet()`. [FluentNHibernate: What is the effect of AsSet()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054076/fluentnhibernate-what-is-the-effect-of-asset)

Comment: Thank you very much. It's work now. 

but when I use `Iesi.Collections.ISet<Course>`, I got this error => "The non-generic type 'Iesi.Collections.ISet' cannot be used with type arguments"

Then, I use ICollection<Course> instead.

Comment: @Siripongz: I did not test the code and googled for the wrong namespace `Iesi.Collections.ISet` instead of `Iesi.Collections.Generic.ISet`. I updated the answer. Thank you for finding the error.